# Scheduling a asp.net function?

Tags: asp.net, schedule

Is it possible for user  who access my page to run a schedule task in asp.net? any reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page can turn on a flag to run a scheduled process, than a windows service can be setup to monitor that flag (stored in DB or file), when its turned on, run the process.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET itself can't run a scheduled task, but you can use Powershell or Windows Task Scheduler to queue up and schedule tasks to be run at a later time.

If you want a user to be able to alter them it would probably be easiest to have a task set to call a special ASP.NET page which would then run any logic needed to actually do the tasks scheduled by users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SQL database backend, you can always create SQL Agent jobs to run and use your ASP.net application to control them. (When to start, frequency, etc)